# Force browser to encode ajax post differently

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, encoding

I'm posting profile results cross-domain and the browser is encoding the @ symbol in the post which is causing processing functions to crash. I don't have access to the server-side processing scripts to decode the values and @ symbol.

**My Question**: Is there any way to force the browser to not encode the @ symbol in the post parameters? Or is there any way to encode it differently where it may be acceptable to the processing scripts.

**Post Prams:**
UserEmail=name%40domain.com&WorkPhone=1-800-000-000&MobilePhone=000-000-000&HomePhone=000-000-0000&EmailAddress=name%40domain.com&ClientNumber=00000&Zip=00000&StreetAddress=000+steet&City=some city&State=Colorado&FirstName=testing+version+61&LastName=name&Clientcomments=this+is+a+description+in+sa+should+map+to+the

**jQuery AJAX:**

```
$.post(
    "https://secure.domain.com/Import.aspx?Provider=1&Client=2&CampaignId=1032&DirectTransfer=true", 
    { UserEmail: 'name@domain.com', WorkPhone: data.WorkPhone, MobilePhone: 
        data.CellPhone, HomePhone: data.MainPhone, EmailAddress: 'name@domain.com',
        ClientNumber: data.ClientNumber, Zip: data.MainZipCode, StreetAddress:  
        data.MainStreetAddress, City: 
        data.MainCity, State: data.MainState, FirstName: data.FirstName, LastName: 
        data.LastName, Clientcomments: data.Discription 
    },
    function(rdata) {
        console.log(rdata)
    },
'script');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.post is really a shortcut for $.ajax so use $.ajax instead and specify the content-type as application/json.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'https://whatever.com',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{"name": "value"}',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

            },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: In that case use processData: false. This will prevent the data from being encoded. When using processData, data needs to be a string so use JSON.stringify() to serialize the json object.